# Image Resolution in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, image-processing, dpi

Can we increase image resolution in flutter? If yes then how can we convert lower quality image to a higher quality image? Secondly how can we calculate dpi of the provided image in flutter ?

Comment: Yes we can increase the image resolution with the help of Deep Learning (Image Super-Resolution).

Comment: Second, why do you need DPI? Do you mean PPI or Resolution?

Comment: @Prabhakaran i need dpi to check the resolution of image. Its the requirement for a project

Comment: consult your professor or teaching assistant about this. clearly they haven't managed to teach you what you need to complete the assignment.